# Is it possible to get an RSS feed of just answers from a particular user?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, activity-tab, rss

I notice that there is a "user feed" link which provides a feed of *all* activity from a given user, but is there a way to slice it up so it's just one thing, answers, or questions, or comments?

Comment: No offense meant here, but I'm having a hard time imagining why you'd want to do that ?

Comment: Not to be overly flippant, but you're a developer, right? Develop something that parses Atom/RSS and filters it! There's a whole site dedicated to apps for the Stack Exchange family of apps, [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/) that will help get it to others if you want to share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

Vote on [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242989/additional-rss-or-atom-feeds) if you'd like to have this implemented.